# How to use RequestContext for render_to_response inside Django FormView?

Tags: django, django-forms

I need to return a render_to_response in case an exception happens inside my FormView derived class.
I'm doing the following (code excerpt, but the rest of the code doesn't cause problems):

```
class ProjectCreateView(FormView):
    """Create view."""

    form_class = ProjectCreateForm
    template_name = 'projects/project_form.html'
    group = None

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """Populate group attribute."""

        self.group = get_object_or_404(Group, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        return super(ProjectCreateView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        """Add current group to context."""

        context = super(ProjectCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['group'] = self.group
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        """Form and logic behind project creation."""

        project_file = form.cleaned_data['project_file']
        thumbnail = form.cleaned_data['thumbnail']
        description = form.cleaned_data['description']

        try:
            <something to try>
        except IntegrityError as e:
            data = {'error':{'msg':_('project_overwrite_error')}}
            return render_to_response('generic_error.html',data,context_instance=RequestContext(self.request))
        except Exception as e:
            return HttpResponse(e)

    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.group.get_absolute_url())
```

If I debug with a breakpoint inside the dispatch() method, everything works fine, and my error template is loaded correctly, and context processors work fine.
When I run it outside debug I get a DatabaseError, which seems to be caused by the access to the django DB session data.

What am I doing wrong? Should I use render_to_response differently inside a generic view?

Comment: Can you please post the full traceback?

Comment: Instead render_to_response you need self.render_to_response.

Comment: Thomas, here it is the stacktrace

Comment: Thomas, here it is the stacktrace https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6460412.
Notice that if I put enough breakpoints (I slow down the debug) the error doesn't raise...

mariodev, why should I use the instence method? Anyway, it has a different signature, and I can't pass it the template name, because 

This is just a condensed version of I will do: call an external method (different module) to manage the exception. That method will "take ownership" of the response flow, so I thought not to use bound methods...
In case I'm not going the right way, what different pattern would you suggest?

Comment: I've noticed that removing the RequestContext argument the exception doesn't happen. Anyway, what causes the crash isn't the RequestContext instance creation (I've tried assigning it to a local variable) but render_to_response...

Comment: The problem seems to be related with SimpleLazyObject, wrapping the auth.user.
If during debugging I access the function, everything works fine. It's enough to have the Variables windows open in PyDev.
If I do not access it, it isn't resolved to the actual user instance (in my case AnonymousUser), and then the template variable lookup fails. I don't know exactly when, but it fails...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is happening but I've solved with a workaround:

```
dummy = self.request.user.is_authenticated()
```

calling is_authenticated before returning render_to_response solves the problem, because request.user is "casted" to the actual user instance, instead of remaining a SimpleLazyObject.

I hope to understand why it happens one day...